# Preserve zone in Spark sql Sting timestamp to Timestamp conversion

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is unique requirement where I want to convert String timestamp in format: `2023-06-07T14:10:38.123+01:00` , I tried converting using format `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'` it is converting it to `2023-06-07 13:10:38.123` but it is dropping the time zone +01:00. I want to make String column to Timestamp and keep String format same `2023-06-07T14:10:38.123+01:00` . I searched multiple sites but still not able to find how to keep same string. Or if it is a non doable requirement then please share your experience.

`spark.sql("select to_timestamp('2023-06-07T16:10:38.123+01:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX') as timestamp").show(truncate=false)` it gives me this:

```
+-----------------------+
|timestamp              |
+-----------------------+
|2023-06-07 16:10:38.123|
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your string as:

```
2023-06-07T14:10:38.123+01:00
```

if you convert it to TIMESTAMP Spark stores it as UTC timestamp:

```
2023-06-07T13:10:38.123
```

or more precisely, the number of seconds since epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z - anyway, the UTC timezone. Spark doesn't store original timezone info.

If you display a timestamp in Spark, it uses default `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format using session time zone. In case yours is '+01:00' it will simply display as:

```
2023-06-07T14:10:38.123
```

You can explicitly format the timestamp and add the offset information using [date_format](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html) function:

```
spark.sql("select date_format(to_timestamp('2023-06-07T16:10:38.123+01:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX')").show(truncate=false)

2023-06-07T14:10:38.123+01:00
```